# What does setting the inner iterator to the outer iterator [ j=i ]do in nested for loops do?

Tags: math, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm working on a coderbyte challenge and upon looking at solutions to a specific problem I see a lot of people using nested for loops that have the inner loop's iterator set = to the outer loops iterator. Creating this type of pattern:

```
      i values         j values
when... i=0    |  j=0,j=1,j=2,j=3 etc.
        i=1    |  j=1, j=2, j=3, j=4 etc.
        i=2    |  j=2, j=3, j=4, j=5 etc.
```

That general concept. What type of pattern does this make and why is it useful?

The code for that would be

```
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(let j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

What use is this? I can't figure out how it could be applied to anything.

Comment: That's a loop over all pairs of indexes `i, j` with `0 <= i <= j < array.length`.

Comment: In the inner loop you meant `j++` instead pof `i++`, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, I did mean j++. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shown codes "pattern" is a triangle. Print any character in the inner loop and a newline in the outer loop to see what I mean.

Especially while mentioning "array", such a pattern can be used for "do something to all pairs of each entry and any OTHER entry" (where "1 and 2" would be considered the same pair as "2 and 1", i.e. order irrelevant).
For that it would not be necessary to do "something" to an "each" entry (selected by the outer loop) and an "other" entry (selected by the inner loop) if the "other" entry has already been selected as an "each" entry by the outer loop in any previous "each/other" combination.
In that case you can select an "each entry" by the outer loop going from start to end through the arrayy, obviously. But you only need to select an "other" entry from those which the outer loop has NOT YET selected.

So in the inner loop you select an entry by starting the loop at the index of the outer loop.

Actually I would expect to start the inner loop at the entry one AFTER the outer loops index, but I assume that your code example is not that precise.
Strictly speaking starting at the outer loops index itself would be "do something to all pairs of any entry and any other entry **or the same entry**". I.e. it would additionally include "1 and 1" and "2 and 2", but still only "1 and 2" and not "2 and 1".